# What is the difference between functor composition and natural transformation?

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

If

- $F$ and $G$ are injective functors between the categories $C$ and $D$
- $H$ is an endofunctor on the category $D$ such that $H∘F = G$
- $η$ is a natural transformation from $F$ to $G$

Then for every morphism $f: x→y$ in the category $C$, we have:

$H((F f)(F x)) = H(F y) = G y = (G f)(G x) = (G f)(H (F x))$

After defining the morphisms

- $H_x: F x→G x$ defined as $H_x = H(F x)$
- $H_y: F y→G y$ defined as $H_y = H(F y)$

we get:
$H_y∘F(f) = G(f)∘H_x$

Which looks the same as the commute rule of the natural transformation:

$η_y∘F(f) = G(f)∘η_x$

Is there an isomorphism between H and η?

I understand that in the general case we could not define a functor H for every natural transformation η, since the image of a functor doesn't have to be a category, but could we define a natural transformation η for every functor H which composes $H∘F = G$?

The only difference I see is that a natural transformation can be defined on "almost categories" which are just missing some compositions arrows, where as a functor is defined on categories, so is a functor just a special case of a natural transformation?

What's the importance on defining the natural transformation on functors vs on these "almost categories"?

Can you please help me understand what am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand.  A functor moves between categories, and a natural transformation moves between functors.  It's two completely different gadgets.

Comment: Natural transformations are the morphisms in a category of functors/diagrams, that much is true.

Comment: I think it's precisely this insight that the Yinon is trying to understand.

Comment: Can a natural transformation be thought of as a functor between the images of 2 functors? assuming their images are categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I might say there is no need to consider injective $F,G$.

The equation: $$H(Ff)(Fx)=(Gf)(H(Fx))$$ Isn't quite a naturality equation, as in: $$\eta_y\circ Ff=Gf\circ\eta_x$$

For a few reasons. Firstly, in the first equation $H$ is only ever playing the role of an object, either $H(Fx)=Gx$ or $H(Fy)=Gy$, whereas $\eta_\bullet$ is an arrow, not an object.

Secondly, while $\eta$ runs $F(-)\to G(-)$, even if you do try to interpret $H$ as an arrow in the above, as in $H(Ff):H(Fx)\to H(Fy)$, this is just an arrow $Gx\to Gy$. It is even just $Gf$ itself. It is not linking $Fx\to Gx$, and it is not linking $Ff$ with $Gf$.

Functors also *act* on things: they associate objects to objects and arrows to arrows. Natural transformations are just bags of arrows, and act neither on objects or arrows themselves.

Finally, you *could* define a natural transformation $F\implies G$ given $G=HF$ **if** you had a natural transformation $\mathrm{Id}\implies H$. Think about what the problem is: you need to find arrows $Fx\to HFx$ for all $x$. There's no reason for these arrows to exist, nevermind the question of existence of a natural transformation, unless you already have a natural association $z\to Hz$.

Functors play very different roles to natural transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, one thing I'm missing, why can't I define for every x an arrow Hx: Fx → Gx simmilar to ηxt? because HFx=Gx, you said they might not exist?

Comment: @Yinon How *would* you define an arrow $H_x:Fx\to Gx$? Where does it come from? We need additional assumptions to say such arrows exist

Comment: I watched the lectures https://youtu.be/KaBz45nZEZw?t=517 In my mind an arrow and a function and a mapping is the same thing, as you can see in the image, so the functor H is defined for each x sending Fx to Gx, you can draw an arrow from Fx to Gx and call it Hx, The functor H is defining a mapping of objects and arrows and you can represent any mapping using arrows by drawing the arrows from the objects the functor acts upon to the result. I don't understand what do you mean by exists, I'm creating those arrows to demonstrate the isomorphism.

Comment: @Yinon CAUTION! In the generality of category theory, objects don't need to 'look like' sets (foundational quibbles aside) and arrows certainly don't need to be functions. $H$ *takes* $Fx$ to $Gx$ as a functorial assignment, $H(Fx)=Gx$. It does not "take" $Fx$ to $Gx$ in the sense of 'drawing a line' $Fx\to Gx$. You can't draw a line if you don't know the relevant arrow exists. You can't create arrows that aren't already given! $H$ maps objects to objects. That is not an arrow in the sense of *morphism*, though it is commonly drawn as such.

Comment: Interesting where can I read more about it? I don't understand the difference between mapping object X to object Y vs a morphism from object X to object Y.

Comment: What if I define the categories C and D to be the category Set, would it be right then?

Comment: We need to be careful with language. Mapping object $X$ to object $Y$ means, there is a function $\mathrm{Ob}C\to\mathrm{Ob}D$ and its image on $X$ is $Y$. *A* mapping from object $X$ to object $Y$ is usually interpretable as there is a 'function' of some kind $X\to Y$: the category will usually be considered a set like category. However it could well just mean "there is an arrow $X\to Y$" and this is not the same thing as a function (what is an element of $X$?) and it certainly is not the same thing as, there is a function of objects under which $X$ has image $Y$

Comment: No. Let's take $D=\mathsf{Set}$ and $H$ the constant functor to $\emptyset$. For any set $X$, $HX=\emptyset$. So I have a mapping *of* $X$ *to* $\emptyset$. BUT, that is not saying there is *a* mapping $X\to\emptyset$. Indeed, no such mapping/arrow/function exists for nonempty $X$ @Yinon

Comment: is it because ∅ is the initial object and in the definition there is no arrow going into it?
If I remove this restriction basically create a category where there is an arrow from every object to every other object, would it be right then?

Comment: @Yinon Initial objects can have arrows going into them. This just happens to be false in $\mathsf{Set}$ (excepting $1_{\emptyset}$). If $D$ has arrows between every pair of objects, then ok, there does exist an arrow $Fx\to Gx$. You could even call it $H_x$ if you want (although, you'd need to *choose* a $H_x$ for every $x$ since you haven't exactly constructed it). But the $H_x$ definitely don't need to be natural in $x$! The $H_x$ wouldn't even be related to $H$ at all. **The data of the functor $H$ does not imply any arrow $Fx\to Gx$**. It is wrong to think of functors as transformation

Comment: What if I construct a new category J1 with the objects and arrows from the images of F and G and I add arrows for each x going from Fx to Gx like the mapping of H.
I then construct another category J2 except instead of H mapping arrows I'm using the natural transformation mappings. would those 2 categories be isomorphic?

Comment: @Yinon You could add one arrow $Fx\to Gx$ but in no sense would it "be like the mapping of $H$". These arrows wouldn't assemble naturally either. I reiterate: though you may *draw* $H:Fx\mapsto Gx$ with an arrow, *there is no arrow* implied by $H$